# UPDATE/DELETE in mysql and get the list of affected row ids?

Tags: php, mysql, rows-affected

Is there an efficient way to get the list of affected row IDs (not the # of affected rows via PHP's mysql_affected_rows(), but the actual row ids that were affected) from an UPDATE or DELETE query in mysql?

In postgresql, there is a RETURNING clause within UPDATE/DELETE queries that can be used to specify values from the affected rows that are returned.

In mysql, the 'brute force' way of getting the affected rows seem to be:
1. Acquire READ LOCK.
2. SELECT to with the WHERE condition of the UPDATE/DELETE query to get the affected row ids.
3. UPDATE/DELETE.
4. RELEASE LOCK.

The above way seems very inefficient. Is there a more efficient way to get the affected row ids in mysql?

Answer (score 15):

You can create a [Trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html)

> Support for triggers is included beginning with MySQL 5.0.2. A trigger
>   is a named database object that is associated with a table, and that
>   activates when a particular event occurs for the table.

the following code creates a trigger on a table named `mytable` which has a field `id`

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytable_delete
AFTER DELETE ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW SET @deletedIDs = CONCAT_WS(',', @deletedIDs, OLD.id)
```

notice that `OLD` refers to deleted row

once you created a trigger on a table you can use it as follows:

```
/* empty parameter defined in CREATE TRIGGER */
Set @deletedIDs = '';
/* perform your query */
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE myotherfield = 'myfilterevalue';
/* get the parameter */
SELECT @deletedIDs AS 'Deleted_IDs';
```

this will return deleted IDs each preceded by a comma in a string

[sql](/questions/tagged/sql) [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) [php](/questions/tagged/php)

Comment: I suggest to use this trigger.
  
`CREATE TRIGGER mytable_delete
AFTER DELETE ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW SET @deletedIDs = TRIM(LEADING ',' FROM CONCAT_WS(',', @deletedIDs, OLD.id))`

This removes the leading comma.

Answer (score 10):

try this, it will return the updated ids as "1,2,3....":

```
SET @uids := '';
UPDATE table_name
   SET some_col= 'some_val'
 WHERE some_col= 'some_val'
   AND ( SELECT @uids := CONCAT_WS(',', @uids, id) );
SELECT TRIM(LEADING ',' FROM @uids);
```

Comment: You should open a new question about that, because it is a different case. You also should include the query you used and the errors that were reported. (if you do, provide me with the link to the new question and I'll be happy to help)

Comment: I solved it, was typing my comment and example and the editor didn't allow me to get a new line, so nevermind.

Answer (score 0):

Using @redmoon7777 answer, it gets the updated `ids` and Concat them to `uids`, but I found out the columns are not updated.

Maybe at the time of his answer, it's updating, but it's more than 8 years ago so I believe it might work on old MySQL versions.

But using it on version **5.7.14** and maybe higher, won't update.

So similar to his solution, I added extra condition to make the columns update

```
SET @uids := '';
UPDATE table_name SET some_col= 'some_val' WHERE some_col= 'some_val' AND ( SELECT @uids := CONCAT_WS(',', @uids, id)) != '';
SELECT TRIM(LEADING ',' FROM @uids);
```