# Getting all effected rown in MySQL UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update, primary-key

Title pretty much says it. I am using the deprecated `mysql_` functions. I've got a query like:

```sql
UPDATE `table`
SET `row` = 'newtext'
WHERE `row` = 'oldtext'
```

Is there an easy way to get all effected row's primary key? Some glorious combination of `mysql_insert_id` and `mysql_affected_rows`? How can I do this without looping and doing each update one row at a time?

Comment: Why do you want the primary keys?

Comment: for logging, it's a cron job.

Comment: should you change the 'WHERE' with pimary column

Comment: I think I'm gonna have to. Just wanted to check for an easier solution first.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873805/update-delete-in-mysql-and-get-the-list-of-affected-row-ids

Comment: @Adelphia . . . The first thing that comes to my mind is a trigger.

Comment: Unless the rows are being updated so quickly that you cannot lock the tables for writing, I think the simplest approach would just be to `SELECT` the primary keys using the same `WHERE` condition and *then* do the same update.

Comment: @ExplosionPills . . . Introducing race conditions *on purpose* into an application seems like a really, really bad idea.  How about doing the two operations inside a single transaction?

Comment: @GordonLinoff that's what I was referring to with respect to locking the tables.  You would have to lock it for writing before doing the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a solution to your problem please refer the following sample code snippet

```
  UPDATE `table` SET `row` = 'newtext' WHERE `row` = 'oldtext'

  select id from table where row='oldtext'
```