# How do I get the rows affected by a MySQL query in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-update, rows

From PHP, if I execute a query like the following with `mysqli_stmt_execute`:

```
UPDATE users 
SET hair_color = 'brown' 
WHERE height > 180;
```

How can I figure out which rows in the table were actually updated and affected by the query?

Please note that I am looking to solve this problem in only PHP, without the use of DB triggers, etc. Very specifically, this question came about because we're trying to remove all triggers from our DB.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Comment: I don't want the number of affected rows, I want the actual rows back. Or rather, the primary keys of the affected rows, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UPDATE/DELETE in mysql and get the list of affected row ids?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873805/update-delete-in-mysql-and-get-the-list-of-affected-row-ids)

Comment: if you take a look at [`Return Values`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php#refsect1-mysqli.affected-rows-returnvalues) and example # 1 this output return the primary keys

Comment: Noman, which part of example #1 shows that? Thanks.

Comment: Trying to solve this without the use of DB triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string="UPDATE users SET hair_color = 'brown' WHERE height > 180";
//Update Query String which will perform in update query

$update_query=mysqli_query($connection,$string);
//by this we are actually running our update queries.    

$total_affected_rows=mysqli_affected_rows($con); 
//By this line you will get total affected rows

//if you need to select and show all the affected rows then you can make a 
//query

$sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE height > 180");
```

Comment: Marking this as the right answer because this was the only suggested way to handle this problem without the use of DB triggers. Should note that the SELECT statement with the same WHERE clause as the UPDATE can be execute before or after the UPDATE. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `mysqli_stmt_affected_rows()` to get the affected rows

check here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php