# Get id of records updated with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql, upsert

I want to know if there is a way to get the ID of records updated with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UDATE`.

For example, I have the `users` table with the following schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx-users-email` (`email`)
);
```

and insert some users:

```sql
INSERT INTO users (email, username) VALUES ("pioz@example.org", "pioz"),("luke@example.org", "luke"),("mike@example.org", "mike");
```

the result is:

```
+----+------------------+----------+
| id |      email       | username |
+----+------------------+----------+
|  1 | pioz@example.org | pioz     |
|  2 | luke@example.org | luke     |
|  3 | mike@example.org | mike     |
+----+------------------+----------+
```

Now I want to know if, with a query like the following one, is possible to get the ID of the updated records:

```sql
INSERT INTO users (email, username) VALUES ("luke@example.org", "luke2"),("mike@example.org", "mike2") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE username=VALUES(username);
```

In this example ID 2 and 3.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873805/update-delete-in-mysql-and-get-the-list-of-affected-row-ids) is similar and shows on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8873956/3536236) using MySQL variables to collect such data.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the only solution is to used a stored procedure. Here is an example for one row, which could be expanded.
See dbFiddle link below for schema and testing.

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE add_update_user(IN e_mail VARCHAR(25), IN user_name VARCHAR(25) )
> BEGIN
>     DECLARE maxB4 INT DEFAULT 0;
>     DECLARE current INT DEFAULT 0;
>     
>     SELECT MAX(ID) INTO maxB4 FROM users;
>     INSERT INTO users (email, username) VALUES 
>        (e_mail, user_name) 
>        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE username=VALUES(username);
>       
>     SELECT ID INTO current FROM users WHERE email =e_mail;
>     SELECT CASE WHEN maxB4 < current THEN CONCAT('New user with ID ', current, ' created')
>       ELSE CONCAT('User with ID ', current, ' updated') END Report;
>       /*SELECT CASE WHEn maxB4 < current THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;*/
> END
> ```

> ```
> call add_update_user('jake@example.com','Jake');
> ```
>
> ```
> | Report                     |
> | :------------------------- |
> | New user with ID 6 created |
> ```

> ```
> call add_update_user('jake@example.com','Jason');
> ```
>
> ```
> | Report                 |
> | :--------------------- |
> | User with ID 6 updated |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=04ddc9d1c7f05cc713f59ce22c03ee70)*

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:  Use the technique in the ref manual -- see `LAST_INSERT_ID()`

Plan B:  Get rid of `id` and make `email` the `PRIMARY KEY`